# How to create a ROC curve for a model which has log of odds as response?

Tags: r, linear-regression, roc

I have a question on plotting `ROC curve` for my model which has `log of odds` as the `response`. For example:

```
model<-lm((ln(y/1-y)~Temp+RH+DmaxT, data=fit) #'y' is a proportion
```

Predicted response was obtained for a new data set as:

```
Predicted_model<-predict(model, newdata, type = 'response')
```

Predicted values were back-transformed to get values in proportion

I have new observations in proportion and I used `0.05` cutoff value to represent control (<0.05) and cases (>0.05)

```
newdata$observed<-ifelse(newdata$observed > 0.05, "cases", "controls")
```

I plotted ROC curve using the following formula

```
roc(newdata$observed, predicted_model_backtrans, legacy.axes = TRUE, plot = TRUE, print.auc = TRUE)
```

With this formula, I got `AUC` value 1 and the plot is different than expected. I couldn't figure out what would be the best way to create `ROC curve` for my model type. Any help would be appreciated.

I also tried to create ROC curve where I changed observed and predicted proportion into binary characteristics (control (`<0.05`) and cases (`>0.05`)) which gave me straight line curve rather than smooth.

Comment: Please post questions only once: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/404873/how-to-create-a-roc-curve-for-a-model-which-has-log-of-odds-as-response

Comment: If you're asking how to do it programmatically, please post a minimal, complete and reproducible example. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve